# Open url link from AlertDialog

Tags: android, url

My program starts with EULA.
EULA is showing in AlertDialog via WebView.
A have links to web site in text. When click on link I receive error message:

```
03-01 18:44:48.421: E/AndroidRuntime(8862): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Instead of using getBaseContext():

```
WebView wv = new WebView(getBaseContext());
```

I put: this

```
WebView wv = new WebView (this);
```

both are context. Both render WebView perfect, but getBaseContext crashes when click on url.